# Show/Hide Div's not submitting form with Client Side Validation and Attributes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application.
Inside the application, I have a Login View which is strongly typed via a `LoginViewModel` class. In addition, the Login View can be accessed by two different types of people `Employees and Management`.

The view is displayed in a `< table >`. The user must first select (from 2 radio buttons) what type of user he is (`Employee or Management`) and from the selection, I change the UI and display (show/hide) certain `div`s.

If `Employee` is selected, I ask for the `Employee Number` and `Password`.

If `Management` is selected, I ask for the `UserCode` and `Password`.

The LoginViewModel has 4 properties:

- -`UserType` (represents the selected radio button)
- -`EmployeeNumber` (represents the textbox for Employees)
- -`UserCode` (represents the textbox for Management)
- -`Password` (represents the textbox for the Password regardless of who is selected)

Since the UI changes according to the selected radio button, I can not use the `[Required]` attribute on both EmployeeNumber and UserCode properties because if I do, the `< form >` won’t submit (since one of the fields will be hidden).

To overcome this limitation/problem, I have to remove the `[Required]` attribute on both properties and presumably do this client side.

For the record, I am not using `MicrosoftMVCValidation.js` but instead `jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`

**Question 1)**

When searching for examples online I’ve seen many of them including this file:

> jquery.**unobtrusive**-ajax.min.js

What’s the purpose of this file and what’s its correlation with client side validation (if any)? 
Do I really need it? Shouldn’t jquery.validate.min.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js suffice?

**Question 2)**

I understand that one could write a custom Validation Attribute and place it on the EmployeeNumber or UserCode property but if I do so (and knowing that I will be hiding one of them in the UI) how do I prevent myself from getting the same issue I had with the `[Required]` attribute? (meaning not being able to submit the form because one is hidden)

Can I simply do this directly in the View? Would anyone be so kind to show me a quick example?

Thanks

Oh and yes…the jquery-1.7.1.min.js is included in the master layout (in case anyone asks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js is not for unobtrusive validation. It is for using the @Ajax html helper (@Ajax.Form, etc).

To answer your second question, I would actually create 2 totally different viewmodels and corresponding forms for this. When user selects with radio button, show the correct form. That means, don't combine Employee and Management into the same LoginViewModel. You can then treat validation, as well as other view logic, separately between the two.

**Update**

To answer your question about strong typing, you would create 2 different (partial) views. One would have @model EmployeeLoginViewModel and the other would have @model ManagementLoginViewModel. To render them on a a single page, there are a few different approaches. You can have a single LoginViewModel that contains an instance each of ManagementLoginViewModel and EmployeeLoginViewModel, and then use @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Employee) and @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Management). However this approach only works if your partial views are in the EditorTemplates folder.

Another approach is to use @Html.Action(), and have 2 different controller action methods to return the partial views.

Comment: Let me see…I create two different ViewModels and define appropriate fields for each and proper [Attributes]. When the user clicks, display appropriate form. But don’t combine the two ViewModels inside the single/parent LoginViewModel. Ok but how to I strongly type the View that will be hosting the 2 forms? Can you have a strongly typed View based on two different ViewModels? I’m a bit confused…should the click of the radio button trigger a call to a different method which in turn displays a different strongly typed View? Is that it? Oh and thanks for the clarification on question 1)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this.

First, you can create a custom attribute that looks for the value of a boolean in your model.  The boolean would be controlled by the radio buttons for the manager, or employee.  If this boolean is true, then it validates if it's false, then it ignores it (basically sets valid to true always).  You could call this attribute ConditionalRequiredAttribute.

this would then look like this.

```
public class MyModel {
     public bool IsManager { get; set; }

     [ConditionalRequired("IsManager", false)] // validates if IsManager is false
     public int? EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

     [ConditionalRequired("IsManager", true)] // validates if IsManager is True
     public string UserCode { get; set; }
{
```

As for how you would create this attribute, you can start with the attribute described here http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

Another way to do this is to use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and again, validate based on the value of your checkbox.

Another way is to leave off the validation, and check it in your model.

Comment: I like the idea but I’m a bit confused as to how (or what) should the clicking of the radio button trigger? Since the click is happening on the client-side and that the form is not yet submitted, how would the custom attribute (on the Server-side) be aware of what has been selected? Perhaps I’ll need a bit more clarification on this.

Comment: @Vlince - Part of creating a custom attribute includes the javascript necessary to do the validition client side as well.  Validation has to be done in both places.

Comment: Wow…after reading Part 1 and Part 2 I now better understand and realize how great these links are! Seriously thank you! I’ve just posted a conclusion and will most likely use your approach in another feature I have. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the `RequiredAttribute`. Instead have both properties as virtual in `LoginViewModel`. Then have an `Employee` model and a `Management` model which override the appropriate properties and set the `RequiredAttribute` as needed. You can still use the same Action, and then inside it based on the selection use `UpdateModel` to fill the appropriate type of model. This won't give you the validation on those fields client side, but you can handle that with javascript and the server side will be handled for you normally.

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand. First I do not need to remove the [Required] attribute on both my properties inside the LoginViewModel is that correct? Then instead of making them public, make them virtual. Then create two additional ViewModels (Employee and Management) which overrides the properties and set a new [Required] attribute if needed. I’ve never used/heard about the UpdateModel, perhaps I need to get myself more familiar with it to better understand your proposed solution, unless, of course, you’d like to quickly show an example (crossing fingers) Thanks Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

Conclusion:

After reading Olivehour, Yuriy and Mystere Man’s different take on this, I came up with the following conclusion:

I believe my initial approach was wrong so I decided to re-think the entire thing and start from scratch.

I’ve decided to follow olivehour’s approach and create a **composite/parent** ViewModel that will hold two ViewModels (one for Employee and one for Management). Each of these will have the form definition and appropriate [Attributes].

The parent View will be strongly typed to the composite ViewModel. The View will then call for two partials (displaying two forms at the same time side-by-side) allowing the appropriate users to decide on which form to use.

Please note that the accepted answer was olivehour’s because I’ve decided to change my approach but I strongly recommend people (if anyone is even reading this) to follow Mystere Man’s link on the complete guide to validation.

Part 1 and Part 2 are a must read for everyone!

Had I not decided to change my approach, I would’ve gone with Mystere Man’s solution.

Thanks